# how to push new data to json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

so lets say i have this objects:

```
{
"8282748274" : "melly",
"2764726482" : "john",
"8268274827" : "carol"
}
```

how do i add new data to it so it would look like this:

```
{
"8282748274" : "melly",
"2764726482" : "john",
"8268274827" : "carol",
"0000000000" : "NewDataHere",
"0000000001" : "MoreNewData",
etc
}
```

i tried using object.push but it didn't work, here's the code i tried to use

```
let newData = {
  "385835638578" : "alex",
  };
  
object.push(newData);
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: `Object.assign(object, newData);`

Answer (score 1):

Objects do not have a `push` method. They are not arrays.

In this case, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const obj = {
  "8282748274": "melly",
  "2764726482": "john",
  "8268274827": "carol",
}

let newData = {
  "385835638578": "alex",
};

Object.assign(obj, newData)

console.log(obj)
```